# Replicating spring effect

Tags: 2d, joints, spring

I want to replicate this spring effect on the stack of popsicles in the attached video. Can you advise some tips/tutorials/ideas/articles? The main goal is so that it can wobble freely and feel more "static" than regular spring effect.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dxj84I-7rVs

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you try to set yourself the position, without using actual joints?

Comment: I don't think this is achieved in some physical way, it looks like each object does some kind of position following on the x-axis(to the previous object).